# Не выполняется рекурсия

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется код:

```
char field[3][3];
void enterX() {
            cout << "Enter X on vertical: ";
            int i;
            cin >> i;
            if (cin.good() && i < 3 && i >= 0)
            {

            }
            else {
                cout << "Please, enter the number 0-2!";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
                enterX();
            }


            cout << "Enter X on horizontal: ";
            int j;
            cin >> j;
            if (cin.good() && j < 3 && j >= 0) {

            }
            else {
                cout << "Please, enter the number 0-2!";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
                enterX();
            }
            field[i][j] = 'x';

    }
```

Задача - считывание номера элемента массива с консоли и вставке в это место символа 'x'. Однако при неверном вводе не происходит рекурсия. В чём проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите отладчиком что же происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то это - `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);` - игнорировать все (ну ладно, `INT_MAX` символов) **до конца файла** - т.е. пока какое-то ^Z не закроет поток...

```
input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

И вообще, я бы делал так (если уж приспичила именно рекурсия):

```
char field[3][3];
void enterX() {
    cout << "Enter X && Y: ";
    unsigned int i, j;
    cin >> i >> j;
    if (cin.fail() || i > 2 || j > 2)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
        cout << "Wrong values!\n";
        enterX();
    }
    else
    {
        field[i][j] = 'x';
    }
}
```

**Update**

Имея типичную оконечную рекурсию, лучше переделать ее в итерацию:

```
char field[3][3];
void enterX()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "Enter X && Y: ";
        unsigned int i, j;
        cin >> i >> j;
        if (!(cin.fail() || i > 2 || j > 2))
        {
            field[i][j] = 'x';
            break;
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
        cout << "Wrong values!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Но без него происходит вечная рекурсия

Comment: У вас она вообще сделана криво. Если вы даже ввели нормально первое число, а второе неверно - рекурсия начнет требовать ввод первого числа... И я же вам написал - добавьте вторым параметром `'\n'`, а не уберите вовсе!

Comment: См. обновленный ответ

Comment: А какие варианты без рекурсии?

Comment: Итерация, конечно.

Comment: Дописал в ответ итерацию...